# How to set expiry dates for Google Drive

Tags: google-drive-api, drive

How can I set expiry dates for Google Drive?

What are the steps to open the way to solve this issue? I need step-by-step instructions to handle this issue.

Comment: why are you repeating yourself? ... I do not wish to sound rude, but your post is a complete mess ... please use the `Edit` button to correct it

Comment: Repeating things is usually read as "I know I should give more details, because the system explicitly told me to. But I cannot be bothered." and tends to hamper benevolent perception of your question. Please try for [ask].

Comment: Admittdely, my edit to help your formatting might increase the urgency of an improvement by you.

Comment: The minimum text requirement is there to encourage you to describe your problem adequately, which you didn't.